# Nvidia drivers installation in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, driver, nvidia

Guys I am using Linux for the first time and I am trying to install the latest Nvidia drivers but the problem is, it is always downloading in a text editor file and it is trying to load the drivers but is failing. 
What is the difference between long-lived Linux and Short-lived Linux?
SO I am getting this problem where the Nvidia drivers are installed as text editor rather than a proper run file. What can I do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure if I can vote to close it, but this has already been answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054954/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: It sounds like you've downloaded a .run file. In order to make this executable use the command ```chmod +x yourfilename``` and then in terminal, run the file by doing ```sudo ./yourfilename```, you need to the sudo because nvidia driver installation requires root privileges.

Answer (score 1):

run this command in your terminal :

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

This will give you all the features you need to run NVIDIA on your device . for exemple :
[image]

ok , now you need to access the following website to download the Nvidia driver :

https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx

From here, you should choose the NVIDIA Driver features that are compatible with your device , as shown in the picture:
[image]

When the installation is completed, go to the file and ensure the script to be runnable run this command :

```
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.73.run
```

(Do not forget to write your file name correctly)

then run this commands :

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install make
```

Then you should disable Nouveau NVIDIA default driver , run this command :

```
sudo bash -c "echo blacklist nouveau > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
sudo bash -c "echo options nouveau modeset=0 >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
```

then type the following commend to check if you are doing right :

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf
```

update kernal initramfs run :

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

and reboot your computer with :

```
sudo reboot
```

now install the NVIDIA driver and restart again your computer :

```
sudo bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.73.run
sudo reboot
```

Comment: This answer has saved me hours and hours of pain at least 3 times when setting up / updating nvidia drivers for linux machines, thank you

Answer (score -1):

if you are using Ubuntu for the first time i would recommend "hadware drivers app" or "Update settings" and choose "additional drivers" and install the driver from there.